# Connect to MicrosoftTeams 3.0.0 using Accesstokens fails with the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am  running the below script to connect-microsoftteams from powershell.

```
$clientSecret = "xxxx"  
$tenantName = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$tenantNameshort = ""
$tenantId = "xxx"
  
$graphResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"  
$graphtokenBody = @{  
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"  
   Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"  
   Client_Id     = $clientId  
   Client_Secret = $clientSecret  
}   
$graphTokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $graphtokenBody


$teamsResource = "https://api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com"  
$teamstokenBody = @{  
   Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"  
   Scope         = "48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239/.default"  
   Client_Id     = $clientId  
   Client_Secret = $clientSecret
  
}   
$TeamsTokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $teamstokenBody

echo $graphTokenResponse
echo $TeamsTokenResponse

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @($graphTokenResponse.access_token,$TeamsTokenResponse.access_token)
```

While running the script, I am getting below error.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At C:\Users\ythan\script.ps1:30 char:1
+ Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @($graphTokenResponse.access_tok ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-MicrosoftTeams], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-MicrosoftTeams,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.Powershell.Connect.ConnectMicrosoftTeams
```

Please help to resolve this.

I am trying this to read the direct routing phone number (lineUri) assigned to the user.
`Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity "UserXXX" | fl RegistrarPool,OnPremLineUriManuallySet,OnPremLineUri,LineUri`

Comment: Hello @Priya - Looks like the token value is null.
Could you please check recheck if token value is present.

Comment: Can you please try with this Scope : **https://graph.microsoft.com/.default**

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT, I tried changing the scope as Scope         = "graph.microsoft.com/.default". It gives 'invalid_scope' error.

Comment: Hi @ChetanSharma-msft, I am able to print the token, it has values. but still same error

Comment: Hello @Priya, even i am getting the same error like you. did some reaserch and found this [document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/7145)in this they are suggesting to open a support request it reaches the team behind the development of the Teams PowerShell module. So they can try to reolve this issue from there end.

Comment: Similar issue is being discussed [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/8623), and seems like it is a known issue and the ETA is also mentioned  there.

Comment: Hi  @RahulKumarShaw-MT, Get-CsOnlineUser command is not working with the version 2.3.1. It gives the error "Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'"

Comment: You have to set **teamAdminstaror** permission for your application it took around 24 hr to work.

Comment: Step : Go to your AzureActiveDirectory->Role and Administrators->Search for Teams administrator -> add assigment -> Select Member ->choose your application for that you want to give persmission

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT, Can we assign role to application? Because I could see only users in the member suggestion list of add assignment.

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT, Can we assign role to application? Because I could see only users in the member suggestion list of add assignment. I have created a group with the 'application' as a member and assigned Teams administrator role to that group. is this ok? . After doing this also, i am getting the same error.

Comment: Hello @Priya, Scrolling only will show user and groups.Search with your application name if can able to see. Assigning role to application (being member of group) this could also work. Please wait for 24 hr to reflect the same.

Answer (score 0):

I also tested the same PowerShell script in my environment I got the same error as you are getting.

[image]

To resolve the issue, you have to use Microsoft Team 2.3.1 version ([current version](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/2.3.1))

[image]

According to the Microsoft team version you have to connect the Microsoft team with the correct command like below.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams  -MsAccessToken $TeamsTokenResponse.access_token -AadAccessToken $graphTokenResponse.access_token -TenantId 'XXXXX' -AccountId 'Application ObjectID'
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT, thanks for sharing this. I am able to connect with teams module in this version using tokens. But 'Get-CsOnlineUser' command is giving the below error with this version of Teams module which was working with 3.0.0. "Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again."

Comment: The command is updated in the description